# Como utilizar o value do options?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extensão

Dentro do arquivo "options.html" eu sei exatamente como funcionar para fazer uma marcação funcionar para habilitar algum conjunto de javascript como...

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test">
    Habilitar
</label>
```

Que vai executar uns códigos a seguir dentro do options.js:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test').checked;

test: test

test: false

document.getElementById('test').checked = items.test;
```

Ai o resultado final vai ser ativado dentro de um exemple.js:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;
var info = 0;

var total_requests = 0;
var processed_requests = 0;

var cookie = document.cookie;

storage.get(function(settings) {
    if (settings.test === undefined) { 
        settings.test = false;
        storage.set({'test': settings.test}); 
    }
    if (settings.test) {
        \\alguma coisa aqui
    }
});
```

Se você entendeu o que eu quis dizer, agora vem minha dúvida; eu estou querendo saber como fazer isso com algum valor de uma configuração que esteja sendo definido em um `<select>`.

```
<select id="exemplo">
    <option value="exemplofoi">Padrão</option>
    <option value="exemplofoi2">Extra</option>
</select>
```

Caso não tenha entendido, eu estou querendo usar o storage.get para ativar um javascript apenas quando este value estiver ativo na página de configurações da extensão.

Resposta:

```
storage.get(function(settings) {
    if (settings.exemplo === undefined) { 
        settings.exemplo = false;
        storage.set({'exemplo': settings.exemplo}); 
    }
    if (settings.exemplo == 'exemplofoi') {
        \\alguma coisa aqui
    }
});
```

Comment: Só da uma melhorada na sua pergunta para que fique o mais simples de se entender

Comment: Fiz um update melhorando um pouco mais os detalhes da pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer pegar o valor do *< option>* que estiver selecionado, vou responder com esse entendimento:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <select id="exemplo">
        <option value="option01">Padrão</option>
        <option value="option02">Opção 2</option>    
    </select>

    <button id="pegar">Pegar Valor</button>
    
<script>
    $("#pegar").click(function(){ 
        var opcao = $('#exemplo :checked').val()
        if( opcao == 'option01' ){
            //chama sua funcao aqui
            alert( 'chama sua funcao na opcao1' );
        }
        if( opcao == 'option02' ){
            //chama sua funcao aqui
            alert( 'chama sua funcao na opcao2' );
        }
            
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim, mas eu quero utiliza-lo para habilitar uma função da extensão.

Tipo: value option01 vai habilitar uma coisa, option02 vai mandar a habilitar outra coisa da extensão. Eu não sei como utilizar storage.get para fazer este processo.

Comment: vou editar para você compreender a ideia de chamar uma funcao se opcao1 e chamar outra se opcao2

Comment: DEU CERTO! Captei sua ajuda com o storage.get e funcionou tudo certinho. Muito obrigado mesmo por ter me ajudado! :D

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar o valor do `option` selecionado basta pegar o value do `select`, afinal quem recebe o atributo `name` é ele, ou seja, quando você seleciona algum `option` você está definindo que o valor do `select` será o valor daquele `option`.

Como um código fala mais quem mil palavras, aqui vai um exemplo usando apenas **Javascript**:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');

console.log(select.value);

var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  alert(select.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Um</option>
  <option value="2">Dois</option>
  <option value="3">Três</option>
</select>

<button id="button">Ver</button>
```

Aqui um exemplo usando **jQuery**:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


  var $select = $('#select');
  
  var $button = $('#button');
  
  $button.click(function(event){
    alert($select.val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Um</option>
  <option value="2">Dois</option>
  <option value="3">Três</option>
</select>

<button id="button">Ver</button>
```

Comment: Sim, mas eu quero utiliza-lo para habilitar uma função da extensão.

Tipo: value 1 vai habilitar uma coisa, 2 vai mandar a habilitar outra coisa da extensão. Eu não sei como utilizar o storage.get  para fazer este processo.